# How can I give a project quote politely? 

Tags: phrases, email

Someone sent me an email, asking for a quote for the project. How can I reply to him in a more polite way?

> I can quote you $100 for this project.
>
> I charge you $100 for this project.
>
> I can do this with $100.

Can you give me more examples (formal/informal)?

Answer (score 4):

> To carry out the work described will cost $100.
>   My quotation for the project is $100.
>   For this project, my charge will be $100.
>   I can do this for $100.

To make the reply more polite you surround it with the usual salutations, thanks and closing formula. Adjusted to desired degree of formality or informality.

Answer (score 3):

"I would charge $100 for the project, with the deliverables consisting of ...".  The important thing is to make sure that the recipient is clear what you are charging for so that you aren't held to a fixed price quote for something you thought was small, quick and easy but the customer turns into something large, time consuming and hard.